# Sticking footer to bottom even if content is not long enough

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to move my footer to the bottom and in the cases if the content is not long enough, then push it to the bottom of the screen. I read that it can be achieved solely by using css, however I couldn't achieve it.

I tried creating columns,

```
<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
           ...
       </nav>

       <div id="content">
          ...
       </div>

       <div id="footer">
          ...
       </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then, in my css, I tried using:

```
#footer {
    height: 30px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: purple;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

but no luck :/

Here I created it in [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/N3XiwwGr9q). Here, I added bunch of `<br>` tags to lengthen the content and added some text underneath. What I want is instead if content is short, stick the footer to the bottom of the page (not where content ends in the middle of the screen); and if content is long, where the content ends just below content.

What am I doing wrong/missing out?

Comment: Use `position: fixed;`, not `position: absolute;` on the footer. Second, move the footer outside the wrapper-div. Third, we have a `<footer>`-element, no need to use `<div id="footer">`

Comment: Also, this could be of use: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/ZZsCwkLenf try also adding some `overflow:auto` to your wrapper

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I tried moving footer outside wrapper div and changing the footer position to fixed. [This is](http://www.bootply.com/heBEOXHixB) what I achieved, but I don't want it to get sticked and always get shown. I want it to stick to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @haxxxton your answer is very true for sticky header, but I want to stick it to the bottom of the page, always. And if the content is too small, then still stick it to the bottom. I don't want the footer to follow me.

Comment: @senty, deleting the `<br />` in my bootply still leaves the footer at the bottom in OSX Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit), http://imgur.com/a/SNvHR are you seeing something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want it to always stay at the bottom, you can use this code. Remove the `<p>` tags and run again to test without text

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 #wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
 }
    #content {
      background: red;
      }
 footer {
  height: 4em;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing odio, vitae nulla luctus consectetuer, cras odio turpis adipiscing lobortis, tempor luctus morbi. Sed vitae id in, vel tempor mattis rutrum, eu non mauris in erat lectus enim, eget morbi quo imperdiet, mi lorem aliquam sed accumsan orci. Rhoncus nonummy turpis ipsum tempus tempor elementum, vestibulum sint tempor, accumsan mauris scelerisque rutrum. Eget rhoncus hendrerit, ipsum ipsum nunc sit ut arcu aenean, urna in justo reprehenderit mollis, suscipit erat, consequat suspendisse turpis duis nec pellentesque tristique. Lectus velit, vestibulum lorem enim turpis a eu mauris, mauris bibendum sociis lobortis sodales sed, eget rhoncus quisque consequat curabitur sit. Sodales velit et convallis interdum quis rutrum, dolor lobortis neque mi eget lorem, sed tincidunt dis convallis. Feugiat in conubia nec ipsum, nec rutrum nisl, vitae id vestibulum sollicitudin fringilla ac ligula, eget rutrum in. Tortor mollis amet, nulla pharetra nec in, vel vulputate nec eu diam, cras massa adipiscing pulvinar, id pulvinar massa dignissim. Quisque lorem enim vel orci vestibulum, consectetuer tincidunt et egestas.</p>
<p>
Donec nunc nec in, ut non lorem eget tortor facilisi sed, eget tempor a duis urna, pellentesque proin blandit et, mollis dictum dictum. Aliquet massa praesent vitae lorem at posuere, id lobortis nec id dignissim lorem nisi, at amet occaecati, duis enim quisque quam est, ultrices nunc semper vivamus praesent aenean nam. Natoque neque adipiscing, ipsum magna libero. Pellentesque mattis, fusce maecenas sit vel, accumsan eleifend et justo cras dui, wisi quisque interdum amet arcu bibendum, ante eget non mattis non. Iaculis congue cras feugiat. Platea aliquet suspendisse, orci nulla aliquam adipiscing in. Nullam libero velit in pellentesque diam est, urna phasellus, pellentesque porta eu. Ante lacus duis amet libero odio, accumsan neque tincidunt imperdiet, wisi praesent diam arcu et, erat aliquam feugiat ultricies tortor ullamcorper. Vestibulum sapien velit, ante fusce cursus volutpat tellus, eros officiis, ridiculus cum eu suscipit, felis dui sed nulla hac neque fermentum. Vivamus sagittis, malesuada nullam, dolor sit sed sollicitudin et maecenas fermentum, non nunc dapibus purus. Aliquam rhoncus aliquam sit fermentum, curabitur nulla accumsan.</p>
<p>
Nec consequat. Purus neque inceptos suscipit dictum, dolor massa ut egestas proin sed ultrices, eleifend at sed sit mi adipiscing sociis. Nostra laoreet metus nulla in. Urna eget, accumsan id mattis morbi, etiam a consequat curabitur, in felis vel. Aliquam feugiat sed, sit ligula sit praesent lobortis orci metus, nulla cursus mi velit vitae, a erat elit, velit ultrices consectetur libero perferendis libero. Risus sed, suspendisse urna in eget voluptas tristique, aliquam justo lectus, rutrum scelerisque, sem nibh qui dictum aliquet lacinia ut. Urna sagittis ac tristique gravida risus aliquam, dictum ipsum ac sodales, felis mauris repellendus porttitor aenean, orci vel feugiat nunc hendrerit. Porta eu, etiam pellentesque mauris et aliquam consectetuer donec, molestie dui magna enim, ac eu erat ut, lectus ligula feugiat urna per. Ornare aliquet ligula, ultricies sint arcu ipsum nulla. Vel ut vitae dui adipiscing.</p>


  </div>
    <footer>This is a footer</footer>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This seems like what I want to achieve, but I need to test one more thing to be sure, however I couldn't change it. What I want is, if the red area gets smaller than height of the screen, then I want the footer to stick to the bottom, rather than sticking to the bottom of content's div. How can I change the red div's height? Please help me. thnxx

Comment: If you want to change the red div's height, but keep the footer at the bottom, that would involve a bit of HTML reorganizing. Gimme a sec.

Comment: With another container inside the `#wrapper`, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

This sends the footer to bottom of the bage no matter how much text you have:

```
.footer {   background-color: #2D2D2D;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
background-color: #000;
height: 30px;/* or however high you would like */ } 

html, body {
height: 100%; } 

.wrapper {   background-color: purple;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -30px; } 

.footer, .push {
30px; } 

.navbar {
background-color: red   }
```

Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding, now it's fixed: http://www.bootply.com/N3XiwwGr9q#

Comment: Exactly what @junkfoodjunkie said. I tried this, but it's following me when I scroll. I want it to stick to the bottom of the page and don't follow me

Comment: sorry, I thought you wanted it to follow. Now it stays at the bottom.

Comment: In the bootply, it doesn't form at the bottom of the content I think. It forms at the bottom of the screen for the initial load, but there are content elements under the footer

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use position: relative on the footer's container element and position: absolute on the footer to actually push it to the end of the container. Position: fixed isn't necessary.

https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This example does the same thing with a container element over the entire page, instead of operating on the html and body tags.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page